# How to solve ValueError: when appending a row to Pandas data from

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data pandas data frame and a function that appends a row to the existing data frame

```
  df = pd.DataFrame()   
  df.columns = ['A', 'Line', 'B']

   # add a new row at the end of non-indexed df
  def addRow(self, colData, colNames):

     l = len(df)

    colList = []


    for x in colData :
       colList.append(str(x))

    new_record = pd.DataFrame([tuple(colDList)])
    new_record['Line'] = new_record['Line'].astype(int)

  I am getting following error 
  Traceback (most recent call last):



File 
  line 207, in addRow
  new_record[colName] = new_record[colName].astype(int)
   File "site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3054, in astype
    raise_on_error=raise_on_error, **kwargs)
    File "python-3.6.1/linux_x86_64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3168, in astype
    return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
   File "core/internals.py", line 3035, in apply
  applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
 File "site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 462, in astype
values=values, **kwargs)
 File "internals.py", line 505, in _astype
  values = _astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
   File "ckages/pandas/types/cast.py", line 534, in _astype_nansafe
   return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
    File "pandas/lib.pyx", line 983, in pandas.lib.astype_intsafe 
   (pandas/lib.c:16816)
     File "pandas/src/util.pxd", line 74, in util.set_value_at (pandas/lib.c:69655)
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Can someone help me solving the value error

Comment: Try to use this to convert values to int `new_record['Line'] =  pd.to_numeric(new_record['Line'], errors='coerce')`. The error you got because there are some values in Line column that can't be converted to int.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Sai in the comments, because how to convert `'A'` to integer, so use `pd.to_numeric`:

```
new_record['Line'] = pd.to_numeric(new_record['Line'], errors='coerce')
```

Lol, Now you love pandas :-)